# He was mad or madly in love with her?

Tags: adverbs, adjectives

I found this in Swan's PEU

> ***He was <del>mad</del> madly in love with her.***

It says adverb modifying adverbial phase. But...

> ***He was mad in love with her*** --sounds okay to me as I consider *mad* as an adjective there.

Is the latter sentence okay or *mad* should be considered as an *adverb* **only** and thus it must be *madly.* The sentence on its own is fine I think but it's my opinion.

Comment: It sounds like something I'd hear in casual conversation amongst teenagers, but your English teacher would insist on *madly* unless it was intentional vernacular usage.

Comment: You'll find it in Jeremy Irons' film, "Lolita" (1997). "...we were hopelessly madly in love...".

Comment: @M.N: Why stick with the film, if the _book_ has "All at once we were madly, clumsily, shamelessly, agonizingly in love with each other;"

Comment: @oerkelens: You're absolutely right. Unfortunately, I didn't have access to the book so I tried to provide "Maulik V" with the next best thing.

Answer (score 3):

In another Michael Swan's grammar book called "How English Works" he explains that:

"We also use adverbs before (1) adjectives, (2) past participles, (3) other adverbs, and (4)**prepositional expressions**."

1. It's terribly cold.
2. This is very badly cooked.
3. You're driving unusually fast.
4. He was madly in love with her.

Answer (score -1):

I think only if you consider *mad in love* as a phrase in itself.
It would be something like

> He was "mad in love" with her.